# opencart,in new page dont display sidebar though i created new layout

Tags: php, opencart

I have created a advanced search module.It is working properly But problem is i want to show sidebar like categories in the new page.I have created layout and route.

In the search result page sidebar is disappear. Though in module page I've assigned it to the new layout. I'm using *version 1.5.4.*

In my `.tpl` file, I added the `"column_left"`. The code is shown below:

```
<?php echo $header; ?>
<section id="contentWrapper">
    <?php echo $column_left; ?>
    <?php echo $column_right; ?>

    <section id="mainContent">
        <div id="content">
            <?php echo $content_top; ?>
            <?php echo $content_bottom; ?>
        </div>
     </section>
</section>
<?php echo $footer; ?>
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: if your search results are all rendered via jquery, you should also add table data to the rendered html. Check your jquery maybe what you are looking for is there, In the other hand everything should work fine as search.tpl is a separate layout and you should not add the code in your .tpl but simply assign the module.

Comment: Bendo you answered me yesterday.In homepage just above footer there is search module.Result displaying new page but sidebar disappear

Comment: I am also experiencing something like this (without creating any new stuff) with existing modules. For example "Category Module" is not displayed in Product's Layout (it does display in all other "Layouts")! I believe something has been messed up in Layouts. I am using OpenCart 1.5.6.1

Comment: Avijit can you provide a link so  i can further check, it may be that the search box is directing results in another page that can not be specified by layout for example if you use a results.tpl and you do not associate it with a controller might have the behavior you specified. but without the link or the code that is used in your search module i can not give you a clear answer.

Comment: I have created layout and wrong route.SOLVED,